# Laravel API Resource not returning data with one to many relationship

Tags: laravel

In my DoctorController, I have show method like below -

```
public function show(Doctor $doctor){
   DoctorResource::withoutWrapping();
   return new DoctorResource($doctor->load('expertises'));
}
```

In my DoctorResource, if I do

```
public function toArray($request){
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

It returns -

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "mobile": "1234567890",
    "email": null,
    "avatar": null,
    "bio": "Lorem Ipsum 2",
    "email_verified_at": null,
    "mobile_verified_at": null,
    "is_account_verified": 0,
    "account_status": "Active",
    "created_at": "2020-12-03T07:45:07.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-03T10:49:30.000000Z",
    "expertises": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "expertise": "ABC",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "doctor_id": 1,
                "expertise_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-12-03T10:49:29.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-12-03T10:49:29.000000Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "expertise": "XYZ",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "doctor_id": 1,
                "expertise_id": 2,
                "created_at": "2020-12-03T10:49:29.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-12-03T10:49:29.000000Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want to return certain fields from my DoctorResource, So I did this but it is giving me an error. **Exception: Property [expertise] does not exist on this collection instance.**

```
   public function toArray($request){
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'mobile' => $this->mobile,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'avatar' => $this->avatar,
            'bio' => $this->bio,

            'expertises' => [
                'name' => $this->expertises->expertise
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: `$this->expertises` is a Collection, so you can't access `expertise`. You could do `$this->expertises->first()->expertise` to get `'ABC'`, or `$this->expertises->pluck('expertise')` to get an array `['ABC', 'XYZ']`. But regardless, the way you're trying to do it now is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have define another Json Resource to do that:

first you can retrive the model and add keys and values based on each model properties like :

```
public function toArray($request){
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'mobile' => $this->mobile,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'avatar' => $this->avatar,
            'bio' => $this->bio,

            'expertises' => ExpertiesResource::collection($this->experties);
        ];
    }
```

and you have to define Resource Collection as Follow:

```
class ExpertiesResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
          "id" => $this->id,
          "exp" => $this->exp,
          .....
        ];
    }
}
```

when your JsonResource has an **Array of Object(Resource)**, you have to Define That Resource and make use of it like `use App\Http\Resources\ExpertiesResource`

Comment: i am editing and will be availible in couple of minutes

Comment: Answers are saved as a draft as you type them, don't need to post your answer until it is complete :) (But thanks for posting a comment; should stave off the downvotes in the meantime)

Comment: Ok, I got it. So, if I need a separate expertise resource which will return all the fields from the expertise model, then I have to make 2 expertise resource. Right?

Comment: NO, one Doctor Resource, and one Expertise Resource. Doctor Resource has a field name "expertise" which holds a **collection** of Expertise Resource

Comment: Suppose I need only 'expertise' from DoctorResource, So in ExpertiseResource, I return - `public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
          "expertise" => $this->expertise,
        ];
    }`   And for another resource suppose I need 'expertise' & 'id', So in that scenario, will this ExpertiseResource work? Or I have to define a new separate ExpertseResource2 which will return - `public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
          "id" => $this->id,
          "expertise" => $this->expertise,
        ];
    }`

Comment: you have to write another one. its better to write a Definition Resource Class for Each Type of Data Your App Returning.  I have an App with Model name **Entity** but for multiple scenario i want different aspect of it. so i have multiple JsonResource such as **EntityDistributor, EntitySaleable, EntityCompleteResource**, ...

Comment: also you could use `'expertises' => $this->experties` but you couldnt instruct which inner attribute you want in output